# JPA criteria Updatequery not really updating anything

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am not able to have update to really happen with `Updatequery`. Having a simple test class:

```
@Entity
@ToString(callSuper = true)
// query just for logging purposes
@NamedQuery(name="TestEntity.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TestEntity t")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;    
    private String message = "not altered";
}
```

and a test like:

```
@Slf4j
@DataJpaTest
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation =
                                Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestEntityUpdateTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private void buildTestEntity(int i) {
        em.persist(new TestEntity());
    }

    private void log(Object o) {
        log.info("\n{}", o);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testUpdate() {
        IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach(this::buildTestEntity);
        TypedQuery<TestEntity> tq =
                em.createNamedQuery("TestEntity.findAll", TestEntity.class);

        // log inserted stuff
        log.info("\nINSERTED rows");
        tq.getResultList().forEach(this::log);

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaUpdate<TestEntity> update =
                    cb.createCriteriaUpdate(TestEntity.class);
        Root<TestEntity> from = update.from(TestEntity.class);
        update.set(from.get("message"), "ALTERED TEXT!");
        int i = em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();

        log.info("\nUPDATED {} rows", i);
        // log updated stuff
        tq.getResultList().forEach(this::log);
    }

}
```

It must be something very simple but I can not see what? I also tried `em.flush()` in every imaginable place.

Should there be some extra `commit()` or some Spring data setting somewhere?

Rows are inserted correctly. I can see corresponding log rows, like:

> TestEntity(super=org.example.spring.entity.updatequery.TestEntity@230a73f2,
>   id=1, message=not altered)

I can see update queries and bindings correct(?):

> Hibernate:
>       update
>           test_entity
>       set
>           message=?
>      ....
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder:65  - binding parameter
>   [1] as [VARCHAR] - [ALTERED TEXT!]

**BUT** after update I do not see the change, but:

> TestEntity(super=org.example.spring.entity.updatequery.TestEntity@230a73f2,
>   id=1, message=not altered)

Relevant parts from `pom.xml` (ask for more):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your test happens in a single transaction, so the first time you load the entities, they're stored in the session cache. And the second time you load them, they're just retrieved from the session cache again: update queries bypass the cache.

You need to clear the EntityManager before fetching the entities again.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I was unable to resolve how to do it. I feel a bit dummy since not trying `em.clear()` just `em.flush()` :) Anyway I find it a bit odd that em is not aware of updateQuery-changes in the same transaction. I mean that if I made the changes in the entities those of course would be seen immediately.

Comment: Queries are simply translated to SQL and executed. If the JPA engine had to parse and understand the queries, and apply them on the locally loaded entities, it would basically have to reimplement a database engine. Update queries are not common in typical JPA based apps anyway: you normally update the entities directly.